# Probability question candies 36 , 6 friends

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

You have a bag of 36 candies you want to give to your 6 friends. The company that makes the candies guarantees that exactly 6 of the candies in the bag are red, the most delicious color. Anyone who doesn't get a red candy will be so upset that they will stop being your friend! But the candies are in identical wrappings, so you are forced to give each friend 6 candies and hope for the best. What's the probability you lose one or more friends?

Comment: Not asking the answer but can someone explain how to approach it ?

Comment: You have shallow friends

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: First, use the fact that $\mathbb{P}(\text{"you lose one or more friends"})=1-\mathbb{P}(\text{"you don't lose any friend"}).$ Then what is the probability that each friend gets exactly one red candy? Determine the probability $p_i$ for $i$-th friend to get exactly one candy given the fact that the $j$-th friend for $j<i$ got exactly one candy too. Finally, multiply $p_i$'s to get the joint probability.

Comment: "Determine the probability pi for i-th friend to get exactly one candy and multiply pi's to get the joint probability. " - you should prove that these are independent

Comment: The probabilities $p_{i}$ are not meant to be independent. What I meant is: determine the probabilities that $i$-th friend gets exactly one candy given that fact that each friend before got exactly one candy as well. I edited the answer.